# Customized Spring Security without Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-security

1. I am using my own MVC implementation and I am not sure, whether the Spring Security isn't designed specifically for the Spring MVC implementation. Is it still okay to use it?
2. It is not clear to me, which parts of Spring Security I should use and which I don't need to. I suppose I don't need the URL filters as I need to validate the access specifically on the URL parameters in my controllers (for instance to check whether *User* is the owner of the *Article*). Something like:

   ```
   if (request.getUser().isAllowedTo("EditArticle", 27)) {...}
   if (request.getUser().isAllowedTo("CategoryManager", 123)) {...}
   if (request.getUser().isInRole("Admin")) {...}
   ```
3. I could not find some clear way of users logging in/out programmatically. I've implemented my `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` classes to handle the users with JPA, but I don't see a way, how I can proceed with login and logout in my controllers.

EDIT:

I don't see a way how to put the `<form>` in my Freemarker templates - the only way of creating the form I found is with:

```
<http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/home.htm"/>
</http>
```

How can I configure the structure of the login form? Can I create it by myself?

What I would like the most is to be able to handle the login by myself (for example with DWR) and not to use the magic j_security_checks...

It would be great, if I could handle the login request by myself and ask the auth service to login the user by myself (so I could easily use Direct Web Remoting (DWR)):

```
 if (user.username.ok() and user.password.ok()) {
     authService.setUser(user);
     authService.setLoggedIn(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Spring security is not limited to spring mvc and can be used with your own framework implementation. It provides handy services for authentication and session management.
2. Spring is very convenient to use to leverage access by certain URLs but not limited to. You will be able to get which roles the current user has at the moment from the spring context and all the custom info you would include in your UserDetails object. There are number of ways to restrict access to certain actions by certain roles. However the code like `if (request.getUser().isAllowedTo("EditArticle", 27)) {...}` I think it will be simplier to check by yourself.
3. Login and logout are done by calling specific urls. For login: /j_spring_security_check. For logout: /j_spring_security_logout.