# Java Web Application - Admin/Public Users

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, jdbc

Consider a Simple Java Web Application which has login and registration functionality using JSP, Servlets, JDBC, JSTL. I need to make the application have normal public_users, and then admins. They both utilize the same login page, although when a public user log's in, it has different dashboard utilities, compared to the administrator's when they login.

I have tried searching on Google, although I have not been able to find a concrete answer.

Is it possible to have these two users utilize the same login page? If any of the users have valid credentials, based on the status 'admin' or 'public_user' Is there a way of redirecting them to 2 totally different pages?

Within the database, how would I set a particular user to admin, or invite someone to be an administrator?

Suggestions would be appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use spring security where you get the advantage of specifying the USER_ROLE while a user registers and while loging in you can get the credentials and based on the USER_ROLE you can redirect to a specific url.

References [1](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/), [2](http://khangaonkar.blogspot.in/2011/04/spring-security-tutorial-1.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049319/how-to-use-spring-security-for-user-role-management)

Comment: Excellent, thank you for you response. Is there a way to connect this spring framework to a phpyMyAdmin database?

Comment: -1?? please!! I would like to know why the -1

Comment: sorry If I had missed out on this reference http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

it shows how you can connect your database through configuration.

Comment: I didn't apply the negative value to your response. Thank you immensely.

Comment: Helping each other is the aim,Reputation is fun side :) keep helping.Do not care about the -1 without reasons.

Comment: I know that @user2660806 you couldn't, even if you wanted to. No problem. If you have any further question, feel free to ask.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Sure, That is why am not deleting this answer even if it costs me 2reps :P. But on the other had down voting without a reason sucks!

Comment: @codeMan Let them enjoy their 125+ reputation privileges :)

Comment: @codeMan Quick question. Can I implement the spring security, without the Spring MVC application tutorial?

Comment: Sorry wihtout using Spring Application package or whatever*

Comment: @user2660806 yes, offcourse you can. Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818675/customized-spring-security-without-spring-mvc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829256/how-to-use-the-spring-security-filters-without-an-application-context

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yeah... I am sure they have heard of "With more power comes more responsibilities" :)

Comment: @codeMan Ha ha ..good one :) have a nice day.

Comment: @codeMan Excellent! You're a legend. Final question, do I create a pom.xml? or can I place that stuff else where: I am starting of with this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to cop up it with.

There are some frame works (tiles ..etc).

If you don't want to go for it use `JSTL` include directives with conditions for different users
       Assuming most of the page is common for all users,Only the body part might change.

So making a seperate Jsp for each type and including in Main jsp in an idea.

In the nut shell We can maintain with a single `jsp` too,where we can maintain conditions in our `controller`
       .But A seperate `jsp` for each type of purpose costs almost nothing and easier to maintain

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use 2 resources and grant authorization, based on a realm and <security-constraint> and <auth-method> FORM </auth-method>, in web.xml . See this :
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html
 The second way would be to use portal technology and grant permissions by portlet in the same page. But, you said you are using JSP/Servlet.
 The worst way is to use a single resource, get request parameters (user & password) and manipulate page content by what you've got from request ( but, this is a ...'first time programming with JSP/Servlets' solution).

Comment: Thank you for your response, yeah I am in the process of learning, and looking for the most simple approach I can tackle so I know what is happening. If I use the <security-constraint> tag within the deployment descriptor, whenever I utilize it can it be from a input form? Not a thing that pops up on the screen?